# show image in mail contact form 7

Tags: forms, uploads, plugin-contact-form-7

I am using contact form 7.
I have a file field to upload images. 
Code of file field in contact form 7

```
[file* image filetypes:jpg|png|gif]
```

I need to display the uploaded image in mail using contact form 7. How can i do that?

Comment: Have you got it working attaching the images to the emails as per [http://contactform7.com/file-uploading-and-attachment/](http://contactform7.com/file-uploading-and-attachment/)?

Comment: Does that answer your question, or are you still trying to get the attached images to be displayed in the emails?

Comment: I am not trying to get the attached images to be displayed in the emails. I didn't know that there is an option for attach files. So i mentioned like that. It's enough to attach the files in mails. Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 3):

As per my comments, it seems you are trying to attach images to emails rather than 'show' them.

Since you have `[file* image filetypes:jpg|png|gif]` what you need to do is put `[image]` in the 'File Attachments' box in the Contact Form 7 settings.

This is from the Contact Form 7 [File Uploading and Attachment](http://contactform7.com/file-uploading-and-attachment/) doc.

Comment: Hi, is there any way to display uploaded image in our mail content? I created a online application form with profile picture file field. I want to display profile picture in mail template.